# Why don't Tufte classes have subsubsections?

Tags: tufte, tufte-book

Why do Tufte classes (handout and book) not have subsubsections? How can I add them? In general, how can I add other sublevels below subsection?

Comment: Because Edward Tufte thinks you should not have more than two levels of section headings (he has written books about this). The Tufte classes are built to reflect his design philosophy. If you only want some of it, it may be easier to start with a standard class and cherry pick the features you want and design them using `titlesec` and `geometry` (or use the `memoir` class).

Comment: @WillieWong - Your comment could also be an answer

Comment: @DG' I expanded my comment a bit and made it an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why do Tufte classes (handout and book) not have subsubsections?

The [Tufte classes](https://tufte-latex.github.io/tufte-latex/) were created to match the typesetting and design philosophies of Edward Tufte, many of which are described in the [Sample Book](https://ctan.org/pkg/tufte-latex?lang=en) distributed along with the Tufte-LaTeX package, and some of which you can find in [this forum discussion](https://www.edwardtufte.com/bboard/q-and-a-fetch-msg?msg_id=0000hB). A key design philosophy of Tufte's is that you should never use more than two levels of section headings, hence, no subsubsections.

> How can I add them?

Internally Tufte-LaTeX uses `titlesec` to define its styles. The section headings are defined in [tufte-common.def](https://github.com/Tufte-LaTeX/tufte-latex/blob/master/tufte-common.def) (see starting around line 1620 in the file). It turns off the `\subsubsection` and `\subparagraph` levels by redefining them to throw an error:

```
\renewcommand\subsubsection{%
  \@tufte@error{\string\subsubsection is undefined by this class.
    See Robert Bringhurst's _The Elements of 
    Typographic Style_, section 4.2.2.
    \string\subsubsection was used}
    {From Bringhurst's _The Elements of Typographic Style_, section 4.2.2: Use as 
    many levels of headings as you need, no more and no fewer.  Also see the many 
    related threads on Ask E.T. at http://www.edwardtufte.com/.}
}
```

So to restore `\subsubsection`, you should make a personal copy of the tufte class files, edit the `tufte-common.def` file and comment out that redefinition, and furthermore use `titlesec` to create a formatting/style for subsubsections that fits within the general aesthetics.

For reference, you can consult the [`titlesec` manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec?lang=en) as well as the style definitions for chapters and sections included in the `tufte-common.def` file.

> In general, how can I add other sublevels below subsection?

Since Tufte classes are based on the standard LaTeX classes, and customized using `titlesec` and `titletoc`, you can make use of `titlesec`'s ability to add additional section level headings. See the section "3.9. Creating
new levels and changing the class" in the `titlesec` documentation.

---

**Finally**, the Tufte-LaTeX packages makes many very deliberate design choices, setting things up in a way that is hard for authors to diverge from the design philosophy of Tufte (e.g. turning off support for `\subsubsection` explicitly). If you'd rather have the flexibility, I'd suggest you just copy the style yourself using `titlesec` and `geometry` (cf. the code in `tufte-common.def` for the specifications) over a based class, or, if you are adventurous, use the [`memoir` class](https://ctan.org/pkg/memoir?lang=en) instead. The `memoir` class is very customizable, and has built-in support for the margin tables and figures that are hallmarks of Tufte's design.